# Unity C# script variable not changing in game when changed in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Very new to Unity, I'm making a tactical RPG game similar to Fire Emblem. I've followed a tutorial on movement from [this](http://www.gameprogrammingacademy.com/unity-tutorial-tactics-movement/) website and followed everything he did.

The player character can only move 5 tiles in the directions +z, -z, +x, -x on a 12x12 tile grid, however I want it to move 6. In the TacticsMove.cs script, there is this variable: `public int move = 5;` with the amount of the variable being how many tiles the player moves. I've changed the variable to `public int move = 6;` and saved the script, but everything is the exact same as before.

**I want `public int move = 6` to allow the player to move up to 6 tiles instead of 5**. There are no comments on the tutorial or youtube videos of this happening so the next place im coming to is here. My code is below, I don't know if all of this is relevant. If you need me to add/remove something, tell me.

TacticsMove.cs

```
ï»¿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TacticsMove : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public bool turn = false;

    List<Tile> selectableTiles = new List<Tile>();
    GameObject[] tiles;

    Stack<Tile> path = new Stack<Tile>();
    Tile currentTile;

    public bool moving = false;
    public int move = 6;
    public float jumpHeight = 2;
    public float moveSpeed = 2;
    public float jumpVelocity = 4.5f;

    Vector3 velocity = new Vector3();
    Vector3 heading = new Vector3();

    float halfHeight = 0;

    bool fallingDown = false;
    bool jumpingUp = false;
    bool movingEdge = false;
    Vector3 jumpTarget;

    public Tile actualTargetTile;

    protected void Init()
    {
        tiles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Tile");

        halfHeight = GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.extents.y;

        TurnManager.AddUnit(this);
    }

    public void GetCurrentTile()
    {
        currentTile = GetTargetTile(gameObject);
        currentTile.current = true;
    }

    public Tile GetTargetTile(GameObject target)
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Tile tile = null;

        if (Physics.Raycast(target.transform.position, -Vector3.up, out hit, 1))
        {
            tile = hit.collider.GetComponent<Tile>();
        }

        return tile;
    }

    public void ComputeAdjacencyLists(float jumpHeight, Tile target)
    {
        //tiles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Tile");

        foreach (GameObject tile in tiles)
        {
            Tile t = tile.GetComponent<Tile>();
            t.FindNeighbors(jumpHeight, target);
        }
    }

    public void FindSelectableTiles()
    {
        ComputeAdjacencyLists(jumpHeight, null);
        GetCurrentTile();

        Queue<Tile> process = new Queue<Tile>();

        process.Enqueue(currentTile);
        currentTile.visited = true;
        //currentTile.parent = ??  leave as null 

        while (process.Count > 0)
        {
            Tile t = process.Dequeue();

            selectableTiles.Add(t);
            t.selectable = true;

            if (t.distance < move)
            {
                foreach (Tile tile in t.adjacencyList)
                {
                    if (!tile.visited)
                    {
                        tile.parent = t;
                        tile.visited = true;
                        tile.distance = 1 + t.distance;
                        process.Enqueue(tile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void MoveToTile(Tile tile)
    {
        path.Clear();
        tile.target = true;
        moving = true;

        Tile next = tile;
        while (next != null)
        {
            path.Push(next);
            next = next.parent;
        }
    }

    public void Move()
    {
        if (path.Count > 0)
        {
            Tile t = path.Peek();
            Vector3 target = t.transform.position;

            //Calculate the unit's position on top of the target tile
            target.y += halfHeight + t.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.extents.y;

            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target) >= 0.05f)
            {
                bool jump = transform.position.y != target.y;

                if (jump)
                {
                    Jump(target);
                }
                else
                {
                    CalculateHeading(target);
                    SetHorizotalVelocity();
                }

                //Locomotion
                transform.forward = heading;
                transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                //Tile center reached
                transform.position = target;
                path.Pop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            RemoveSelectableTiles();
            moving = false;

            TurnManager.EndTurn();
        }
    }

    protected void RemoveSelectableTiles()
    {
        if (currentTile != null)
        {
            currentTile.current = false;
            currentTile = null;
        }

        foreach (Tile tile in selectableTiles)
        {
            tile.Reset();
        }

        selectableTiles.Clear();
    }

    void CalculateHeading(Vector3 target)
    {
        heading = target - transform.position;
        heading.Normalize();
    }

    void SetHorizotalVelocity()
    {
        velocity = heading * moveSpeed;
    }

    void Jump(Vector3 target)
    {
        if (fallingDown)
        {
            FallDownward(target);
        }
        else if (jumpingUp)
        {
            JumpUpward(target);
        }
        else if (movingEdge)
        {
            MoveToEdge();
        }
        else
        {
            PrepareJump(target);
        }
    }

    void PrepareJump(Vector3 target)
    {
        float targetY = target.y;
        target.y = transform.position.y;

        CalculateHeading(target);

        if (transform.position.y > targetY)
        {
            fallingDown = false;
            jumpingUp = false;
            movingEdge = true;

            jumpTarget = transform.position + (target - transform.position) / 2.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            fallingDown = false;
            jumpingUp = true;
            movingEdge = false;

            velocity = heading * moveSpeed / 3.0f;

            float difference = targetY - transform.position.y;

            velocity.y = jumpVelocity * (0.5f + difference / 2.0f);
        }
    }

    void FallDownward(Vector3 target)
    {
        velocity += Physics.gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        if (transform.position.y <= target.y)
        {
            fallingDown = false;
            jumpingUp = false;
            movingEdge = false;

            Vector3 p = transform.position;
            p.y = target.y;
            transform.position = p;

            velocity = new Vector3();
        }
    }

    void JumpUpward(Vector3 target)
    {
        velocity += Physics.gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        if (transform.position.y > target.y)
        {
            jumpingUp = false;
            fallingDown = true;
        }
    }

    void MoveToEdge()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, jumpTarget) >= 0.05f)
        {
            SetHorizotalVelocity();
        }
        else
        {
            movingEdge = false;
            fallingDown = true;

            velocity /= 5.0f;
            velocity.y = 1.5f;
        }
    }

    protected Tile FindLowestF(List<Tile> list)
    {
        Tile lowest = list[0];

        foreach (Tile t in list)
        {
            if (t.f < lowest.f)
            {
                lowest = t;
            }
        }

        list.Remove(lowest);

        return lowest;
    }

    protected Tile FindEndTile(Tile t)
    {
        Stack<Tile> tempPath = new Stack<Tile>();

        Tile next = t.parent;
        while (next != null)
        {
            tempPath.Push(next);
            next = next.parent;
        }

        if (tempPath.Count <= move)
        {
            return t.parent;
        }

        Tile endTile = null;
        for (int i = 0; i <= move; i++)
        {
            endTile = tempPath.Pop();
        }

        return endTile;
    }

    protected void FindPath(Tile target)
    {
        ComputeAdjacencyLists(jumpHeight, target);
        GetCurrentTile();

        List<Tile> openList = new List<Tile>();
        List<Tile> closedList = new List<Tile>();

        openList.Add(currentTile);
        //currentTile.parent = ??
        currentTile.h = Vector3.Distance(currentTile.transform.position, target.transform.position);
        currentTile.f = currentTile.h;

        while (openList.Count > 0)
        {
            Tile t = FindLowestF(openList);

            closedList.Add(t);

            if (t == target)
            {
                actualTargetTile = FindEndTile(t);
                MoveToTile(actualTargetTile);
                return;
            }

            foreach (Tile tile in t.adjacencyList)
            {
                if (closedList.Contains(tile))
                {
                    //Do nothing, already processed
                }
                else if (openList.Contains(tile))
                {
                    float tempG = t.g + Vector3.Distance(tile.transform.position, t.transform.position);

                    if (tempG < tile.g)
                    {
                        tile.parent = t;

                        tile.g = tempG;
                        tile.f = tile.g + tile.h;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    tile.parent = t;

                    tile.g = t.g + Vector3.Distance(tile.transform.position, t.transform.position);
                    tile.h = Vector3.Distance(tile.transform.position, target.transform.position);
                    tile.f = tile.g + tile.h;

                    openList.Add(tile);
                }
            }
        }

        //todo - what do you do if there is no path to the target tile?
        Debug.Log("Path not found");
    }

    public void BeginTurn()
    {
        turn = true;
    }

    public void EndTurn()
    {
        turn = false;
    }
}
```

Tile.cs

```
ï»¿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tile : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public bool walkable = true;
    public bool current = false;
    public bool target = false;
    public bool selectable = false;

    public List<Tile> adjacencyList = new List<Tile>();

    //Needed BFS (breadth first search)
    public bool visited = false;
    public Tile parent = null;
    public int distance = 0;

    //For A*
    public float f = 0;
    public float g = 0;
    public float h = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (current)
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.magenta;
        }
        else if (target)
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        }
        else if (selectable)
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
        }
        else
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        adjacencyList.Clear();

        current = false;
        target = false;
        selectable = false;

        visited = false;
        parent = null;
        distance = 0;

        f = g = h = 0;
    }

    public void FindNeighbors(float jumpHeight, Tile target)
    {
        Reset();

        CheckTile(Vector3.forward, jumpHeight, target);
        CheckTile(-Vector3.forward, jumpHeight, target);
        CheckTile(Vector3.right, jumpHeight, target);
        CheckTile(-Vector3.right, jumpHeight, target);
    }

    public void CheckTile(Vector3 direction, float jumpHeight, Tile target)
    {
        Vector3 halfExtents = new Vector3(0.25f, (1 + jumpHeight) / 2.0f, 0.25f);
        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapBox(transform.position + direction, halfExtents);

        foreach (Collider item in colliders)
        {
            Tile tile = item.GetComponent<Tile>();
            if (tile != null && tile.walkable)
            {
                RaycastHit hit;

                if (!Physics.Raycast(tile.transform.position, Vector3.up, out hit, 1) || (tile == target))
                {
                    adjacencyList.Add(tile);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PlayerMove.cs

```
ï»¿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : TacticsMove 
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        Init();
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward);

        if (!turn)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!moving)
        {
            FindSelectableTiles();
            CheckMouse();
        }
        else
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    void CheckMouse()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider.tag == "Tile")
                {
                    Tile t = hit.collider.GetComponent<Tile>();

                    if (t.selectable)
                    {
                        MoveToTile(t);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Im using unity version 2019.3.12f1.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Updating the initial value of a public field in a script does not magically update all the components of that script that are already present in a scene. You'll have to select those and update the value in the inspector.

Comment: Oh ok. Yeah I updated Move in the inspector and that solved the problem. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Etienne de Martel hints, Unity saves your public variables in the scene along with all the other GameObject/Component data, and restores that data on load

Field initializers are the default values for *new* components, they do not set the values for existing components even with a recompile.

I've been through this a few times myself.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, variables that have been serialized (which means it is visible in the inspector using [serialize] or it is set to public) will always overwrite scripts. This means that the moment u save ur script after u have create a variable and before u start the program, it  can only be adjusted using the inspector